# Orthogonal basis versus non-orthogonal basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question about the non-orthogonal and orthogonal basis.

Let's say we have non-orthogonal independent basis $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$.
If I want to represent a vector $x$ using two of them (either $x_1$ and $x_2$ or $x_1$ and $x_3$ or $x_2$ and $x_3$), then $x$ can be represented as $x=a_1x_1+a_2x_2+r_1$, where $r_1$ is a residual. It essentially projects $x$ onto $x_1$ and $x_2$ plane. Let assume that using $x_1$ and $x_2$ can give the smallest residual $r_1$.

Now if I use gram schmits orthogonalization to make $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ orthogonal to each other which gives orthogonal basis $e_1$, $e_3$ and $e_3$, can I get a residual $r_2$ (using two of the basis $e_1$, $e_3$ and $e_3$) which is smaller than $r_1$?

My question is does the gram schmits orthogonalization give better or compact vector representation?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: I would assume it could, but doesn't necessarily.  Why would you think otherwise?

Comment: I would like to find the two basis that can produce the smallest residual. But I am not sure if gram-schmits orthogonalization can help.

Comment: Gram-Schmidt doesn't optimize the length of the "residual".  So it may or may not do what you want.  But you could always just choose an orthogonal basis where your vector $x$ is in the span of $2$ or even just $1$ of your basis vectors.

Comment: Assume the basis vectors are fixed so I cannot guarantee that $x$ is in the span of 2 basis. Typically, there will be always a residual. I know it will not optimize the length of the residual if we use all of the basis vectors. My question is what if we only choose two of them?

Comment: How are your basis vectors fixed if you can use Gram-Schmidt to get new ones?  Are you saying that $1$ of your basis vectors has to be fixed?

Comment: What I mean is I were given three non-orthogonal basis vectors (all of them are fixed) and I need to use them to represent any new vector $x$. But I can still use gram schmidt to get new ones, right?

Comment: Gram-Schmidt will give you $2$ new basis vectors and leave one of them (whichever you choose) alone (assuming all of your originals were non-orthogonal).

Comment: OK, in that case, it is. But what if we do not do the rotation (or other operations) and only use the gram schmidt?

Comment: Yes, basically there will be three different orthogonal basis vector sets. Does any one of them will produce smaller residual?

Comment: The Gram-Schmidt process will not necessarily make your residual smaller or larger.  It will, in general, change it, but you have no way of determining whether it'll increase or decrease it without calculating it.  And each of your eight choices (not $3$) will produce a different resulting residual.

Comment: OK, I just want to know if there is any possibility that it can reduce the residual if I use only two of them. I need to further look into this.

Comment: I suggest you think about it more, try a few examples, and if you still can't figure it out, reformulate your question a bit so it's a little clearer exactly what you're assuming and what you'd like to know.

Comment: I will do that. Thanks a lot for the discussion.